# Set default language for domain

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have one site with 2 domains one `example.de` and one `example.com` its a multilanguage site, so i have urls like this `example.de/de/content` and `example.de/en/content` etc, and same on `com` domain.

Default language is `de` for this two domains, but for `example.com` i need `english` to be default language.

i thought i can change it in `settings.php` with `$conf['language_default']` like this:

```
$conf['language_default'] = (object) array(
  'language' => 'en', 'name' => 'English', 'native' => 'English',
  'direction' => 0, 'enabled' => 1, 'plurals' => 0, 'formula' => '',
  'domain' => 'www.example.com', 'prefix' => '', 'weight' => 0, 'javascript' => ''
);
```

its working but for both domains... . also i managed to redirect users to `en` on `example.com` (my home page is a node with nid `89`)

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node) {

        if ($node->nid == 89) {
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.example.com') {
             header('Location: http://www.example.com/en');
            }
        }

    }
```

**but its not an option**

Is there any solution to change default language for my `example.com` domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though I'm surprised if there's not an option in the user interface, according to [`language_default`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_default/7), it appears you could set the default language as a $conf variable in the shared settings.php file.

Something like

*settings.php:*

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){

  case 'www.example.com':

    $conf['language_default'] = (object) array(
      'language' => 'en', 'name' => 'English', 'native' => 'English',
      'direction' => 0, 'enabled' => 1, 'plurals' => 0, 'formula' => '',
      'domain' => 'www.example.com', 'prefix' => '', 'weight' => 0, 'javascript' => ''
    );

    // Example per-domain cache prefix if using memcache
    $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'en_';

  break;
  case 'www.example.de':

    $conf['language_default'] = (object) array(
      'language' => 'de', 'name' => 'German', 'native' => 'German',
      'direction' => 0, 'enabled' => 1, 'plurals' => 0, 'formula' => '',
      'domain' => 'www.example.de', 'prefix' => '', 'weight' => 0, 'javascript' => ''
    );

    // Ensures cache varies by domain
    $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'de_';

  break;

}
```

**Update**: Added example [`memcache`](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) cache key prefix setting - to ensure cache varies per domain, if required.

Comment: Sounds good, but what about caches?

Comment: i can turn off cache with `cacheexclude module` for my main page, thanks for answer gonna try it now

Comment: @neok I'm not saying caches *will* mess up. I only wanted to say you need to *test it thoroughly*, unless David Thomas knows they will or will not work OK. If possible, leave them be.

Comment: Glad to hear it. As long as cache varies by / is set per domain, it shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: @DavidThomas I would add `default:` before `case 'www.example.de':`. Without `break;`. For future, to be sure there will be *some* language set in case of domain name change / direct IP access et cetera.

Comment: @molot, If no `$conf` override is set, the core [`language_default`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_default/7) function will provide the default language. So, a default case is an option, but probably not necessary here.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I think the user interface option can be found here: /admin/config/regional/language/configure

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to change the default language? It would be enough to change current language depending on the domain. I think the best way is, to alter the current language of all types with the function:
[hook_url_language_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_api_language_init/7). This would be an code example:

```
function custom_api_language_init() {
  // Current path
  $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $domains = array('www.example.com' => 'en');

  // Global language object and get languages
  global $language;
  $languages = language_list();


  if (isset($domains[$url])) {

    $langcode = $domains[$url]

    $new_language         = $languages[$langcode];
    $new_language->domain = $url;

    // Set url options
    $options['language'] = $new_language;
    $types = language_types();

    // Set all language types and language domains
    foreach ($types as $type) {
      $GLOBALS[$type] = $new_language;
      $GLOBALS[$type]->domain = $new_language->domain;
    }
  }
}
```

Here you find a similar thread: [How to set multiple domains for one language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63490/how-to-set-multiple-domains-for-one-language)

Comment: It is possible some modules on his site uses default language for their tasks, not only current one. Making them behave as people expect them to is perfectly valid reason. Also, if he wants to allow users change language in their profile, and leave default to "use site's default", changing current language makes little sense.

Comment: But why use a default language when it's not the default because it changes?

Comment: It's default per domain, not default overall. Like different default image in different image fields - no one questions that, right? ;)

Comment: @Mołot Ok, I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it in a comment, but I believe it may be the correct way to do it, so I post it as an answer. In

```
/admin/config/regional/language/configure
```

you can set both User interface text language and Content language based on URL, session, user preference, browser language and default language.

Answer (score -1):

in your template.php use the following code. :

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
   global $language;
   if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.example.com' && $language->language != 'de') {
       header('Location: http://www.example.com/en');
   }
}
```

Comment: as you can see i did the same, its working, but when i change language to `de` i will be redirected to `en` again

Comment: I have update my answer. it work like this ?

Comment: default language is `de` so this wont work(i need to set `en` as default language for `com` domain ... thats the problem